# Ok really struggling here Repl.it says that line 3 is incorrect because of something to do with the semicolon

Tags: python

```
import random
x = randint(1, 10):
  if x ==(1):
    print ("yay")
    MathDragon.getsHit()
    MathDragon.sayHealth()
  else:
    print ("no")
    MathDragon.sayHealth
```

Comment: Is this your actual code? What is the first line supposed to do? Why does it have a `:` at the end?

Comment: Also, why are the `MathDragon` lines indented more than the `print` lines? What _is_ `MathDragon`? Why does the last `sayHealth` not have parentheses?

Comment: sorry stack overflow isnt working for me right now and i cant get my code to apear propaly

Comment: Well we can't help you without seeing an accurate representation of your code. Paste it into your question, then select it and press Ctrl+K or click the `{}` button to indent it by four spaces. SO will treat it as code.

Answer (score 1):

```
from random import randint

x = randint(1, 10)

if x == 1:
    print ("yay")
    MathDragon.getsHit()
    MathDragon.sayHealth()
else:
    print ("no")
    MathDragon.sayHealth()
```

Python is an 'indenting language' - your tabs/4 spaces matter.

Also, didn't need a colon after x assignment plus some other mistakes - see above